# COVID19 Vaccine Clinical Trials

Tags: covid-19, vaccination, united-states

I am interested in learning about the details of the Phase 3 clinical trial designs for the Moderna, Pfizer/Biotech, and AstraZeneca/Oxford vaccines.
I expect that the trial designs would be published at ClinicalTrials.gov, but I'll be darned if I can figure out how to navigate to each of these trials.
Hopefully one of the members of medical sciences group can guide me.

(One of the things I am interested in is how and to what extent are various demographic groups represented. For example, of the approx 15,000 vaccine recipients in one of the trials, how many are male, African American, 55 years old, and in fair to poor health)

If I can determine the Clinicaltrials.gov Identifier Code for any of the above trials that would be a major step forward.

Answer (score 2):

For the results you are interested in you need the full text of the publications.

For Pfizer/BioNTech vaccine (BNT162b2 mRNA):

- N Engl J Med 2020; 383:2603-2615

  DOI: [10.1056/NEJMoa2034577](https://doi.org/10.1056/NEJMoa2034577)

  Clinical Trial: [NCT04368728](https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT04368728)

For Moderna vaccine (mRNA-1273):

- N Engl J Med 2020; 383:1920-1931

  DOI: [10.1056/NEJMoa2022483](https://doi.org/10.1056/NEJMoa2022483)

  Clinical Trial: [NCT04283461](https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT04283461)

For Astra Zeneca vaccine (ChAdOx1 nCoV-19/AZD1222):

- Lancet. 2020 Aug 15;396(10249):467-478

  doi: [10.1016/S0140-6736(20)31604-4](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0140-6736(20)31604-4)

  Clinical Trial: [NCT04324606](https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT04324606)

For Janssen vaccine (Ad26.COV2.S):

- N Engl J Med. 2021 Jun 10;384(23):2187-2201

  doi: [10.1056/NEJMoa2101544](https://doi.org/10.1056/NEJMoa2101544)

  Clinical Trial: [NCT04505722](https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT04505722)

Answer (score 0):

Finally found at least the Moderna Trial at [ClinicalTrials website](https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT04470427), still searching for others.

This study description makes no mention of ethnicity targets, but Moderna's website (as of Sept 11 2020) has a graph of enrollees by ethnicity.  Also states that as of Sept 11 2020 had not yet arrived at enrollment goal (24,000 of planned 30,000) [Moderna website](https://www.modernatx.com/cove-study)